# Looking for combinations of an array with undertermined length

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, permutation, combinations

I am working on a personal project and i am stuck at finding the combinations of all array elements as shown below. I am able to find out all combinations when i have a defined number of arrays, but unfortunately i don't.

Here is the documented code:

```
$C = array(
"I" => array(
    0   =>  array("I_1_1"),
    1   =>  array("I_1_2")
),
"L" => array(
    0   =>  array("L_1_1"),
    1   =>  array("L_2_1"),
),
"K" => array(
    0   =>  array("K_1_1"),
    1   =>  array("K_1_2"),
    2   =>  array("K_2_1"),
    3   =>  array("K_2_2"),
),
);
```

Currently $C has 3 elements, but this is very variable, as in you can have 2+ 
Also, each array inside $C is of variable length too and can reach a max length of 144 but this is very rare..

Anyway, my goal is to get the php script to ouput this :

```
I_1_1       L_1_1       K_1_1
                        K_1_2
                        K_2_1
                        K_2_2

            L_2_1       K_1_1
                        K_1_2
                        K_2_1
                        K_2_2

I_1_2       L_1_1       K_1_1
                        K_1_2
                        K_2_1
                        K_2_2

            L_2_1       K_1_1
                        K_1_2
                        K_2_1
                        K_2_2
```

I made it on purpose not to repeat the first 2 columns in the output just so you can see the "direction" of the combination but eventually the output will be an array containing all possible combinations like such :

```
$result = array(array("I_1_1","L_1_1","K_1_1"),array("I_1_1","L_1_1","K_1_2")....
```

and so on..

I don't know if i made myself clear or got you even more confused but in case any more details are needed please let me know.

Thanks in advance to everyone who helps me out, i really appreciate all the effort you guys put in to help people like me.

**Edit: ** Would it be better for me to change the array structure than to use this one to be able to generate the permutations easier?

Comment: I wanna see if this can be done with n dimensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the array can only go three deep, you can do:

```
$combos = array(array());
foreach($C as $D) {
    $old_combos = $combos;
    $combos = array();
    foreach($D as $E) {
        foreach($old_combos as $combo) {
            $combos[] = array_merge($combo, $E);
        }
    }
}
```

If it's variable depth, then you'll need some awesome recursion.

Comment: thanks, yup that works as you said, but unfortunately i don't know how deep the array goes because it depends on user inputs

Comment: Then you're looking at some funky recursion or similarly funky while loops. I'd recommend changing the way that you're getting user input.